# Convert dataframe numeric column to character

Tags: r

I have a data frame with character and numeric columns, when plotting a PCA later on, I need to plot character columns so I wanted to convert column "station" to character.

The data frame:

```
coldata <- data.frame(Location = c(West,West,East,East),
                          Station = c(1,2,3,4),
                          A = c("0.3","0.2","0.8","1"))
```

And the type of columns:

```
sapply(coldata, mode) location station A
    "character" "numeric" "numeric"
```

I would like to have this:

```
sapply(coldata, mode) location station A
"character" "character" "numeric"
```

Can a column be labelled as "character" if containing numbers? Or would I have to convert the numbers into words: ie: 1, 2, 3,4 to one, two, three, four?

I have seen many posts converting character into numeric, but not numeric to character.

Comment: `coldata$Station <- as.character(coldata$Station)`

Comment: Just do `coldata$Station <- as.character(coldata$Station)` as per usual

Comment: `"4"` is different than `4` here, no need to spell out numbers.

Comment: Yes ``"1"`` is a character while ``1`` is a numeric (integer). You can simply do like Sotos said if you  simply want to modify one column. This question is a duplicate tho.

Comment: note that `A` may not be numeric in the sense you can believe it is: as you put on quotes, it's been imported as factor so you won't have 0.3, 0.2, etc. but 1, 2, 3, 4 (factor levels) (or is it just a typo in your example, as the missing quotes for `Location` ?)

Comment: @Cath it was a typo on the example, station and A are both numeric therefore without "". Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can do  that and that should work :

```
coldata$Station<-as.character(coldata$Station)
```

Comment: Thats what Toucan and Sotos said in the comments.

Comment: some people don't think to read it first(like me) i thinks that is better this way